# Seaborn scatterplot does not color correctly 'hue'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, hue, scatter

I am having some trouble with coloring my scatterplot markers. I have a simple dataframe with a value "pos" and two other values, "af_min" and "af_max". I want to color the markers based on some conditions for af_x and af_y, but since I don't any column to exploit as a hue, I created my own column "color".

```
       pos      af_x      af_y  color 
0  3671023  0.200000  0.333333    2.0
1  4492071  0.176471  0.333333    2.0
2  4492302  0.222222  0.285714    2.0
3  4525905  0.298246  0.234043    2.0
4  4520905  0.003334  0.234043    1.0
5  4520905  0.400098  0.000221    0.0
6  4520905  0.001134  0.714043    1.0
7  4520905  0.559008  0.010221    0.0
```

Now, i create a scatterplot using seaborn and a seaborn palette in this way:

`sns.scatterplot(data = df,  x="af_x", y="af_y", hue="color", palette = "hsv", s=40, legend=False)`

But the result is the following: as you can see, one hue does not get colored, as there are only two colors, blue and red. [image: Attempt using hsv palette].

Now something VERY weird happens: to circumnavigate the problem, I built my own palette ad added it to the seaborn istance. But the scatterplot instead of getting colored with the shades I picked, it gets colored with some colors I used in another script some time ago, and there's no way to change them. Here the plot: [image: Scatter with personal palette]
and here's the code:

```
           #violet      #green      #orange
 colors = ['#747FE3', '#8EE35D', '#E37346']
 sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))

 sns.scatterplot(data = df,  x="af_x", y="af_y", hue="color", s=40, legend=False)
```

Here I put the entire script so that you can replicate it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

lst = [[3671023, 0.200000, 0.333333], [4492071, 0.176471, 0.333333],
      [4492302, 0.222222, 0.285714], [4525905, 0.298246, 0.234043],
      [4520905, 0.003334, 0.234043], [4520905, 0.400098, 0.000221], 
      [4520905, 0.001134, 0.714043], [4520905, 0.559008, 0.010221]
      ]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['pos', 'af_x', 'af_y'])

afMin=0.1
afMax=0.9

df['color']=np.nan
for index in df.index:
  afx=df.loc[index, "af_x"]
  afy=df.loc[index, "af_y"]
  if ((afx >= afMin and afx <= afMax) and (afy < afMin or afy > afMax)):
      df.loc[index, "color"] = 0
  elif ((afy >= afMin and afy <= afMax) and (afx < afMin or afx > afMax)):
      df.loc[index, "color"] = 1
  elif ((afy >= afMin and afy <= afMax) and (afx >= afMin or afx <= afMax)):
      df.loc[index, "color"] = 2

sns.scatterplot(data = df,  x="af_x", y="af_y", hue="color", palette = "hsv", s=40, 
legend=False)

plt.savefig("stack_why_hsv.png")

           #violet      #green      #orange
colors = ['#747FE3', '#8EE35D', '#E37346']
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))

sns.scatterplot(data = df,  x="af_x", y="af_y", hue="color", s=40, legend=False)
plt.savefig("stack_why_personal.png")
```

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your first example, is that the `hsv` palette has the same color at its start and at its end. This is because "h" in ["hsv"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is a circular variable, going from 0 to 360 degrees. Matplotlib default uses 3 colors, uniformly spaced over the range of colors, so using the red from the start, the cyan from the center and again the red from the end. So, `hsv` isn't the most adequate color scheme in this case. See [matplotlib's available colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) and [seaborn's extensions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html).

The hsv palette:
[image: hsv palette]

For your second example, [`sns.set_palette()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_palette.html) sets matplotlib's color cycle, but seaborn itself doesn't always use it. When a numeric hue is given, seaborn default chooses the `rocket` colormap by default. From the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

> The default treatment of the hue (and to a lesser extent, size)
> semantic, if present, depends on whether the variable is inferred to
> represent “numeric” or “categorical” data. In particular, numeric
> variables are represented with a sequential colormap by default, and
> the legend entries show regular “ticks” with values that may or may
> not exist in the data.

The easiest way to use a custom palette, is directly providing it to the function (there is no need to call `sns.color_palette()` as seaborn palettes internally are just lists of colors):

```py
colors = ['#747FE3', '#8EE35D', '#E37346']
sns.scatterplot(data = df,  x="af_x", y="af_y", hue="color", palette=colors, s=40)
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with custom colors]

PS: `set_palette` is used by `scatterplot` when the hue is categorical. Here is an example. I also added the [preferred way to set values to a selection of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values); this would be important for large data frames. Note that the boolean operations on arrays need quite a lot of brackets here.

```py
afMin = 0.1
afMax = 0.9

df['color'] = ""
afx = df["af_x"]
afy = df["af_y"]
df.loc[((afx >= afMin) & (afx <= afMax) & ((afy < afMin) | (afy > afMax))), "color"] = "a"
df.loc[((afy >= afMin) & (afy <= afMax) & ((afx < afMin) | (afx > afMax))), "color"] = "b"
df.loc[((afy >= afMin) & (afy <= afMax) & (afx >= afMin) & (afx <= afMax)), "color"] = "c"

colors = ['#747FE3', '#8EE35D', '#E37346']
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="af_x", y="af_y", hue="color", s=40)
```